# How can I set a static IP address in a Docker container?

Tags: linux, networking, docker

I'm perfectly happy with the IP range that docker is giving me by default `176.17.x.x`, so I don't need to create a new bridge, I just want to give my containers a static address *within* that range so I can point client browsers to it directly.
I tried using

```
RUN echo "auto eth0" >> /etc/network/interfaces
RUN echo "iface eth0 inet static" >> /etc/network/interfaces
RUN echo "address 176.17.0.250" >> /etc/network/interfaces
RUN echo "netmask 255.255.0.0" >> /etc/network/interfaces
RUN ifdown eth0
RUN ifup eth0
```

from a Dockerfile, and it properly populated the interfaces file, but the interface itself didn't change. In fact, running ifup eth0 within the container gets this error:

> RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted Failed to bring up eth0

Comment: You could try using the --net=host option. The container will then be available on the host's IP address.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I re-wrote the Dockerfile to set an interface called docker0 (which is what --net=host will create) with my static IP, built the image and loaded it using --net=host. But docker0 still gets its IP from DHCP and ifup docker0 still doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign static IP to Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937185/assign-static-ip-to-docker-container)

Answer (score 36):

I have already answered this here 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35359185/4094678
but I see now that this question is actually older then the aforementioned one, so I'll copy the answer as well:

Easy with Docker version 1.10.1, build 9e83765.

First you need to create you own docker network (mynet123)

```
docker network create --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 mynet123
```

than simply run the image (I'll take ubuntu as example)

```
docker run --net mynet123 --ip 172.18.0.22 -it ubuntu bash
```

then in ubuntu shell

```
ip addr
```

Additionally you could use
`--hostname` to specify a hostname
`--add-host` to add more entries to `/etc/hosts`

Docs (and why you need to create a network) at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/

Answer (score 15):

I'm using the method written [here](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/) from the official Docker documentation and I have confirmed it works:

```
# At one shell, start a container and
# leave its shell idle and running

$ sudo docker run -i -t --rm --net=none base /bin/bash
root@63f36fc01b5f:/#

# At another shell, learn the container process ID
# and create its namespace entry in /var/run/netns/
# for the "ip netns" command we will be using below

$ sudo docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' 63f36fc01b5f
2778
$ pid=2778
$ sudo mkdir -p /var/run/netns
$ sudo ln -s /proc/$pid/ns/net /var/run/netns/$pid

# Check the bridge's IP address and netmask

$ ip addr show docker0
21: docker0: ...
inet 172.17.42.1/16 scope global docker0
...

# Create a pair of "peer" interfaces A and B,
# bind the A end to the bridge, and bring it up

$ sudo ip link add A type veth peer name B
$ sudo brctl addif docker0 A
$ sudo ip link set A up

# Place B inside the container's network namespace,
# rename to eth0, and activate it with a free IP

$ sudo ip link set B netns $pid
$ sudo ip netns exec $pid ip link set dev B name eth0
$ sudo ip netns exec $pid ip link set eth0 up
$ sudo ip netns exec $pid ip addr add 172.17.42.99/16 dev eth0
$ sudo ip netns exec $pid ip route add default via 172.17.42.1
```

Using this approach I run my containers always with *net=none* and set IP addresses with an external script.

Comment: Just trying this suggestion, but I've run into a problem: setting `--net=none` seems to make it impossible to `--link` containers. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, I never used the --link commands (because my containers don't talk each other)

Comment: No prob. After I posted the comment, I thought about it more and it makes sense that it wouldn't work. But it also makes sense that you can configure multiple containers to communicate with one another by the method you've shown. This seems to be the approach of [pipework](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework) (which I am now attempting to use)

Comment: I got 
_Object "netns" is unknown, try "ip help"._

Answer (score 6):

Actually, despite my initial failure, @MarkO'Connor's answer was correct. I created a new interface (docker0) in my host /etc/network/interfaces file, ran sudo ifup docker0 on the host, and *then* ran

```
docker run --net=host -i -t ...
```

which picked up the static IP and assigned it to docker0 in the container.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Docker containers by default do not have sufficient privileges to manipulate the network stack.   You can try adding  `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN` to the run command to allow this specific capability. Or you can try `--privileged=true` (grants all rights) for testing.

Another option is to use [pipework](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework) from the host.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
docker run --cap-add=NET_ADMIN -d -it myimages/image1  /bin/sh -c "/sbin/ip addr add 172.17.0.8 dev eth0;  bash"
```

Explained:

- `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN` have rights for administering the net (i.e. for the `/sbin/ip` command)
- `myimages/image1` image for the container
- `/bin/sh -c "/sbin/ip addr add 172.17.0.8 dev eth0 ;  bash"`
  Inside the container run `ip addr add 172.17.0.8 dev eth0` to add a new ip address 172.17.0.8  to this container (caution: do use a free ip address *now* and *in the future*). Then run bash, just to not have the container automatically stopped.

**Bonus**:

My target scene: setup a distributed app with containers playing different roles in the dist-app. A "conductor container" is able to run docker commands by itself (inside) so to start and stop containers as needed. 
Each container is configured to know where to connect to access a particular role/container in the dist-app (so the set of ip's for each role must be known by each partner).

To do this:

1. "conductor container"

image created with this Dockerfile

```
FROM pin3da/docker-zeromq-node
MAINTAINER Foobar

# install docker software  
RUN apt-get -yqq update && apt-get -yqq install docker.io 

# export /var/run/docker.sock  so we can connect it in the host
VOLUME /var/run/docker.sock
```

image build command:

```
docker build --tag=myimages/conductor --file=Dockerfile .
```

container run command:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name=conductor1 -d -it myimages/conductor  bash
```

2. Run containers with different roles.

First (not absolutely necessary) add entries to `/etc/hosts` to locate partners by ip or name (option `--add-host`)

Second (obviously required) assign a ip to the running container (use
`/sbin/ip` in it)

```
docker run --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --add-host worker1:172.17.0.8 --add-host worker2:172.17.0.9 --name=worker1 -h worker1.example.com -d -it myimages/image1  /bin/sh -c "/sbin/ip addr add 172.17.0.8 dev eth0;  bash"
```

Answer (score 3):

- [Setup your own bridge](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#building-your-own-bridge) (e.g `br0`)
- Start `docker` with: `-b=br0`

& with [pipework](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework#docker_integration) (`192.168.1.1` below being the `default gateway` ip address):

```
pipework br0 container-name 192.168.1.10/24@192.168.1.1
```

**Edit:** do not start with `--net=none` : this closes container ports.

See [further notes](https://it-offshore.co.uk/linux/debian/36-giving-docker-containers-static-ip-addresses)

Answer (score 2):

I understood that you are not looking at multi-host networking of containers at this stage, but I believe you are likely to need it soon. [Weave](https://github.com/zettio/weave) would allow you to first define multiple container networks on one host, and then potentially move some containers to another host without loosing the static IP you have assigned to it.

Comment: Explain static IP with Weave?  Can't find it in the docs (not that that would be an excuse not to explain the answer properly).

Comment: You can start a container with `-e WEAVE_CIDR=ip:192.168.1.2/24`, and given you have Weave Net running along with proxy environment setup in your shell (`weave launch; eval $(weave env)`), that container should get the IP address you have specified.

Answer (score 2):

pipework also great, but If you can use hostname other than ip then you can try this script

```
#!/bin/bash
# This function will list all ip of running containers
function listip {
    for vm in `docker ps|tail -n +2|awk '{print $NF}'`; 
        do
            ip=`docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' $vm`;
            echo "$ip  $vm";
        done    
}

# This function will copy hosts file to all running container /etc/hosts
function updateip {
        for vm in `docker ps|tail -n +2|awk '{print $NF}'`;
                do
                        echo "copy hosts file to  $vm";
                        docker exec -i $vm sh -c 'cat > /etc/hosts' < /tmp/hosts
                done
}

listip > /tmp/hosts
updateip
```

You just need to run this command everytime you boot up your docker labs
You can find my scripts with additional function here [dockerip](https://github.com/dolphyvn/dockerip)

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that `--net=host` might not always be the best option, as it might allow users to shut down the host from the container! In any case, it turns out that the reason I couldn't properly do it from inside was because network configuration was designed to be restricted to sessions that begun with the `--privileged=true` argument.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness: there's another method suggested on the Docker forums.  (Edit: and mentioned in passing by the answer from Андрей Сердюк).

Add the static IP address on the *host* system, then publish ports to that ip, e.g. `docker run -p 192.0.2.1:80:80 -d mywebserver`.

Of course that syntax won't work for IPv6 and the documentation doesn't mention that...

It sounds wrong to me: the usual wildcard binds (*:80) on the host theoretically conflict with the container.  In practice the Docker port takes precedence and doesn't conflict, because of how it's implemented using iptables.  But your public container IP will still respond on all the *non*-conflicting ports, e.g. ssh.