# What does the Resolver param in nginx do?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, resolver

I am using nginx as a reverse_proxy server with ELB. I am looking for explanation regarding the resolver value I set in the nginx.conf file. My nginx.conf:

```
http {  
   ...

   resolver x.x.x.x valid=30s;

   ...
}

server {

   ...

   set $elb "example.com";

location / { 
    ...

    rewrite ^/(.*) $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://$elb/$1?$args; 

    ...
   }
   ...    
}
```

I followed this - https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/6816375#1166569 and set /etc/resolv.conf value as the resolver value and it works fine. What is standing behind this?

Answer (score 41):

The Nginx `resolver` directive is necessary because the OS resolver is not asynchronous. Nginx is a multiplexing server (many connections in one OS process) and each resolver call can block all connections. This is why Nginx has implemented its own internal non-blocking resolver.

If your config file only contains static DNS names and there are no variables in domain names and you don't want to track IP changes without Nginx reload, you don't need Nginx resolver. It's because in this case all DNS names will be resolved on Nginx start.

But if you need to lookup for domains at runtime, you will need a `resolver`.

Examples

```
location {
   proxy_pass http://example.com;
}
```

`resolver` is not required here since `example.com` will be resolved when Nginx starts/restarts. If `example.com` changes its own IP, Nginx needs to be reloaded for the changes to take effect.

```
location {
   resolver 8.8.8.8;
   proxy_pass http://example.com; # <-- resolver not used here
}
```

Even if you use the `resolver` directive in the config file, this `example.com` will only be resolved at start.

In both examples above if `example.com` is not resolving at the moment, Nginx will not start and will give you an error. It's important if you are starting Nginx inside a container and the other one (proxy_pass target) is not yet started so the DNS name is not ready. In this case you can use a runtime resolving:

```
location {
   resolver 8.8.8.8;
   set $domain example.com;
   proxy_pass http://$domain;
}
```

Dynamic host named (which uses variables) will not work without `resolver` since it is resolved at runtime (at the moment than it is used). Nginx will not start if you are use variables in `proxy_pass` but forgot the `resolver`.

```
server {
  location {
   proxy_pass http://myupstream;
  }
}

upstream myupstream {
  server example.com resolve;
  resolver 8.8.8.8;
}
```

And one more specific case is a servers in `upstream` block. In this example above `example.com` will be resolved at runtime. But in Nginx it is part of a commercial subscription (but you can use Angie fork where it is free)

Comment: Thanks @Terra, I am using dynamic DNS name (ELB), so I do need to track IP changes. Is using /etc/resolv.conf nameserver value is a proper solution?

Comment: Yes, you can use any DNS servers including listed in resolve.conf

Comment: Well, not "any", don't use public DNS. There is some security issues atm. Better to use local DNS resolver.

Comment: We use a resolver simply because NGINX does not work without one. Also, when DNS changes we still have to restart NGINX.

Comment: Does NGINX Resolver require "Plus"?

Comment: @AX there is two resolve directives. The one in upstream block is "Plus", but common directive is free. So if you are using upstream,  you need a "Plus", but for proxy_pass use normal nginx enough

Comment: @DmitryMiksIr Is it possible to use route 53 record created for DNS IP in nginx config as resolver instead of hardcoding DNS IP? e.g., resolver http://dns-router.cloudprovider.com                                             which is route53 record for DNS IP

Comment: @user923499 "The address can be specified as a domain name or IP address" from nginx doc so yes, you can use domain name

Answer (score 25):

Nginx resolver directive is critical to any AWS environment that relies on ELB and proxy_pass. Here is the post that I wrote  recently describing problem and solutions to the static DNS caching by opensource nginx:

[Nginx resolver explained and how to deal with changing IPs](https://distinctplace.com/2017/04/19/nginx-resolver-explained/)

Basically it will boil down to following config for simple case:

```
server {
  listen        80;
  server_name   example.com;

  location / {

    resolver 172.16.0.23;

    set $upstream_endpoint http://service-999999.eu-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com;

    proxy_pass $upstream_endpoint$request_uri;
  }
}
```

Comment: The webpage you linked annoyingly redirects to a page with some advertising with pictures of the Matrix.

Comment: It's a JS popover on the same page. There's a close button at the top right edge of the text box.

Comment: The usability of that link is bad enough that it damages the quality of this answer. I would propose removing the link or replacing with something that's readable.

Comment: will there be any performance impact with using the resolver directive?
As  now each time after valid time, a DNS lookup will happen.

Comment: The answer on the (annoying) posted link seem to be mostly copied from https://www.jethrocarr.com/2013/11/02/nginx-reverse-proxies-and-dns-resolution/ (which has no annoying popups)

Comment: Another blog post on this topic: https://tenzer.dk/nginx-with-dynamic-upstreams/

Comment: These answers suggest a configuring a single-point-of-failure resolver, which is particularly peculiar since we're talking about robustness. Can you specify multiple resolvers for fallback in case the resolver is unresponsive?

Comment: @BobDoolittle You can with nginx >= 1.1.7: `Before version 1.1.7, only a single name server could be configured` http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#:~:text=Before%20version%201.1.7%2C%20only%20a%20single%20name%20server%20could%20be%20configured

Comment: The solution above did not work for me, because `resolver` was ignored if it was nested under `server {}`. This article shows it being set on the top level https://community.f5.com/t5/technical-forum/does-nginx-1-20-or-newer-re-resolve-dns-for-proxy-pass/m-p/303657/highlight/true#M262912, and after doing that it did work as described (setting it on the wrong level does not throw any errors).