# nginx fails to start if one of the many sites in its config file not resolving. "host not found in upstream"

Tags: nginx

Nginx fails to start if one of the "proxy_pass" sites is not up or not resolving anymore, therefore bringing dow ALL of the other sites. How can I make it not care if one of the sites is down.

nginx.conf looks like this:

```
    include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
stream {
        server {
        listen 80;
        proxy_pass insertwebsitehere.com
        }
      }
events{}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setup nginx not to crash if host in upstream is not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845674/setup-nginx-not-to-crash-if-host-in-upstream-is-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a resolver in your conf:

```
...
server {
        resolver           8.8.8.8;
        listen             80;
        proxy_pass         http://insertwebsitehere.com/;
...
```

Comment: what if my domain is internal and not resolvable by 8.8.8.8 ?

Comment: Then use your internal DNS instead of 8.8.8.8 @mismar

Comment: Thank you Amin, that worked. It now resolves. However if there is no record that matches the proxy_pass entry, then in fails to start. I might be asking a wrong question here, but is there a way to make nginx not care if there is a record or not and just skip that particular server entry?

Comment: Yes i think if you set resolver under a location, would ignore that proxy if went down. I suggest to open new question and get answer there @mismar

Comment: And if this answer worked for you, accept that to helping find answer for the others @mismar