# Replicate proxy_pass location behavior with variables

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location, proxypass

So usually when creating a nginx location it would look something like this:

```
location /foo/ {
    proxy_pass http://example.com/;
}
```

With this setup, requests to `/foo/bar` are forwarded to `http://example.com/bar` which is the intended behavior.

However when trying to [prevent caching of the domain name `example.com`](https://serverfault.com/a/593003) or when trying to [prevent nginx from crashing if the upstream host is unavailable at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32846603) the only solution seems to be to not use the target directly in the `proxy_pass` directive, but to instead create a variable containing the target like this:

```
location /foo/ {
    set          $targetUri http://example.com/;
    proxy_pass   $targetUri;
}
```

But this totally changes the setup. As soon as `proxy_pass` contains a variable, it no longer appends anything to the target uri, as the [nginx docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) describe:

> When variables are used in proxy_pass [...]. In this case, if URI is specified in the directive, it is passed to the server as is, replacing the original request URI.

So requests to `/foo/bar` are simply forwarded to `http://example.com/`.

When bringing `$request_uri` into the mix, more than what we want is appended:

```
location /foo/ {
    set          $targetUri http://example.com$request_uri;
    proxy_pass   $targetUri;
}
```

Requests to `/foo/bar` are now forwarded to `http://example.com/foo/bar`.

The only workaround I have found is to resort to regex patterns for the location:

```
location ~ ^/foo/(.*)$  {
    set          $targetUri http://example.com/$1$is_args$args;
    proxy_pass   $targetUri;
}
```

Is there any way to replicate the behavior of `proxy_pass` when using variables without having to regex-match the location? The reason I want to avoid regex is because the location path is based on a user input from which the location block is generated.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the trailing `/` from your `$targetUri` variable so that `proxy_pass` does not have the "optional URI" part in its value. Then use `rewrite...break` to duplicate the original behaviour.

For example:

```
location /foo/ {
    set $targetUri http://example.com;

    rewrite ^/foo(.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass   $targetUri;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm assuming a regex pattern in just the rewrite directive is less processing power intensive than my solution with the regex pattern in the location block would be?