# Docker – fix service IP addresses

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose setup with a bunch of backend services (postgres, redis, ...), a few apps (rails, node, ...) and an nginx on top of it.

The apps are connected to the databases using docker env variables (e.g. `DOCKERCOMPOSEDEMO_POSTGRES_1_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR`), and the nginx is connected to the apps using the docker generated `/etc/hosts`: (e.g. `upstream nodeapp1-upstream { server dockercomposedemo_node_app1_1:3000; }`)

The problem is that each time I restart some service it gets a new IP address, and thus everything on top of it can't connect to it any more, so restarting a rails app requires to restart nginx, and restarting a database requires to restart the apps and the nginx.

Am I doing somethings wrong, or is it the intended behaviour? Always restarting all that stuff doesn't look like a good solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an intended behaviour, there are many ways how to avoid restart of dependent services, I'm using next [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937185/assign-static-ip-to-docker-container/27950035#27950035):

I run most of my dockerized services tied to own static ips using the next approach:

1. I create ip aliases for all services on docker host
2. Then I run each service redirecting ports from this ip into container so each service have own static ip which could be used by external users and other containers.

Sample:

```
docker run --name dns --restart=always -d -p 172.16.177.20:53:53/udp dns
docker run --name registry --restart=always -d -p 172.16.177.12:80:5000 registry
docker run --name cache --restart=always -d -p 172.16.177.13:80:3142 -v /data/cache:/var/cache/apt-cacher-ng cache
docker run --name mirror --restart=always -d -p 172.16.177.19:80:80 -v /data/mirror:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro mirror
...
```