# Looking up a container's address via its hostname dynamically in Nginx

Tags: nginx, docker, dns, docker-network

I'm currently trying to run two containers on a single host, one being an application (Ruby on Rails) and the other Nginx as a reverse proxy and cache. The app is running on TCP port 80. What I want to be able to do is bring down my application container, remove it and then bring it up again without having to restart nginx. The problem is that Nginx only seems to look up the IP of the container once, so if it goes down then back up at a different address then Nginx will just complain that there's nothing there.

I've tried a few things:

- Using `resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=5` to use Docker's DNS
- Using an `upstream` block
- Using a variable to try to get nginx to resolve at runtime.

I'm not sure where else to look but none of these options work if the application is brought up on a different IP address. Is there something I'm missing making this impossible?

Thanks.

Comment: For this to happen, you'll need either a DNS or discovery service, or use static IP for your application container. See this answer if you are running the newest Docker version http://stackoverflow.com/a/35359185/4190526

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up reading through [the 12 factor app](http://12factor.net/) which inspired me to remove the Nginx proxying to Rails upstream altogether, and instead used it as a proxy cache which has an upstream of the external DNS name.