# Log client's "real" IP address in Docker Swarm 1.12 when accessing a service

Tags: nginx, docker, load-balancing, docker-swarm

I have nginx container running as a service in Docker Swarm inside user created overlay network. Both created with:

```
docker network create --driver overlay proxy
docker service create --name proxy --network proxy -p 80:80 nginx
```

When accessing nginx site through a browser, in nginx access log remote address is logged as 10.255... formatted address, what I presume to be the Swarm load balancer address. The question is how to know/log the address of the end client accessing the site and not the load balancer address.

Answer (score 10):

Good catch!, Most people analyzing the nginx `access.log` and client ip is important part of it.

As docker version 1.12.1 the problem exists. nginx will log swarm overlay ip. But client ip logs fine as standalone container. As a work around, you can have a `reverse proxy` pointing to swarm service. I know this is against `High availablity` and `Self Healing` concept of swarm, but seems to be the only work around right now.

sample config: (lets assume swarm service is listening on 8081 on localhost)

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  location / {
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass          http://localhost:8181;
    proxy_read_timeout  90;
  }
}
```

More info can be found on [this github issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/25526).

**Another Option:**

You can use networking in host mode.

```
docker service create \
--name nginx \
--network <your overlay network> \
--publish mode=host,target=80,published=80 \
--publish mode=host,target=443,published=443 \
--replicas 1 \
nginx
```

Comment: I wanted to note that using this in a production environment is a security risk, especially if your application relies on these values to validate the client. The X-Real-IP and X-Forwarded headers can easily be spoofed and should not be relied upon.

Comment: @tkeeler with haproxy you can unset the the variables in the http request and the set real value in the response

Comment: @c4f4t0r - Only if you restrict all HTTP requests to haproxy. Otherwise someone can make a request directly to the server bypassing your haproxy rewrite.

Comment: @tkeeler I think the service need to be exposed to the world only using the lb and nobody can use one single server.

Answer (score 7):

So the way I've worked around this for now is by using the `mode=host` option for publishing the port and pinning the proxy container to a single node like so:

```
docker service create \
--name proxy \
--network proxy \
--publish mode=host,target=80,published=80 \
--publish mode=host,target=443,published=443 \
--constraint 'node.hostname == myproxynode' \
--replicas 1 \
letsnginx
```

Comment: `mode=host` option has been added in Docker 1.13 and is what I'm doing now too.

Answer (score 2):

We had to solve the issue of identifying clients real IPs for our production deployment of Docker Swarm running https://www.newsnow.co.uk/ (`mode=host` was not an option as we needed to run multiple replicas across multiple nodes).

To solve it, we created: https://github.com/newsnowlabs/docker-ingress-routing-daemon, a daemon that modifies the ingress mesh network routing to expose true client IPs to service containers.