# Docker (stopped) container has no IP address

Tags: docker, ip, konakart

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                    NAMES
ca030d3cf1c2        konakart_app                 "/bin/sh -c '/bin/bas"   16 minutes ago      Exited (1) 5 minutes ago                            konakart_app
08909245064b        beantoast/dtkonakart_mysql   "/entrypoint.sh mysql"   54 minutes ago      Up 54 minutes              0.0.0.0:3300->3306/tcp   konakart_db
```

I'm trying to run konakart app and it's database in two different containers. The database seems to be working fine, but the application itself seems to have no IP. 
When I type in `docker inspect ca03` I get the following:

```
            "EndpointID": "",
        "Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "",
        "IPPrefixLen": 0,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "",
```

Any idea of how to assign a my IP address, port 8080 to the konakart_app?

Comment: Did you check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937185/assign-static-ip-to-docker-container

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is simple based on the output of `docker ps -a` result that you posted in the top.

You might have noticed that it is showing status `Exited (1) 5 minutes ago` for the container whose id is `ca030d3cf1c2`. That means, container is stopped.

Once container is stopped, it will not have any `IPAddress`. That's the reason being shown `empty` in the result of `docker inspect ca03` which you posted.

Start the container, you would get the `IPAddress`.

To your last question, you may have that configuration for port forwarding using your `docker-compose.yml` file. Or you may also do it while running `docker run` using `-p <hostport>:<container port>` option.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The cause for a container not to have an `IPAddress` as mention in Rao's answer can be, that the container is exited. A possible reason for this can be, that you don't have space let on your device, if nothing else changed.