# Dockers container image update

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

So let's say I've a .NET Core application running in a container, i'm running it on a custom network with it's own IP in the subnet ( important that the IP stays the same for this app).

I've added some new functionality to my .NET Core application and want to redeploy it. Is it possible that I pull the new image, just stop the container, "update" it's image and restart the container, instead of stopping, removing and running the image again with the right commands for the network and ip?

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately if image was updated, you need to create new container based on new image. No another way.

But you can set static IP for container how explains in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937185/assign-static-ip-to-docker-container?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the info. Yeah I figured that out with the IP, I'll just need to document on what IP I use for each service I'll make then. Thanks!