# How to cure 503 Service Unavailable in Apache running in Docker Container?

Tags: apache, docker, virtualhost, http-proxy, http-error

I am trying to create an Apache virtual host proxy in a Docker container (I am on Docker 1.6), so I did the following:

First set up two Docker containers, each running their own web application:

```
docker run -it -p 8001:80 -p 4431:443 --name build ubuntu:latest

apt-get update
apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php -y
echo “<?php phpinfo(); ?>” >> /var/www/html/info.php
service apache2 restart
```

then

```
docker run -it -p 8002:80 -p 4432:443 --name cicd ubuntu:latest

apt-get update
apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php -y
echo “<?php phpinfo(); ?>” >> /var/www/html/info.php
service apache2 restart
```

Each of these runs perfectly on their respective ports. So next I create a container running Apache:

```
docker run -it -p 8000:80 -p 4430:443 --name apache_proxy ubuntu:latest

apt-get update
apt-get install apache2 -y
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
service apache2 restart
```

This works perfectly on it's own at port 8000.

Then I created a virtual host file for each of the other Docker containers:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName build.example.com
    <Proxy *>
        Allow from localhost
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8001/
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName cicd.example.com
    <Proxy *>
        Allow from localhost
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8002/
</VirtualHost>
```

Then placed both in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` of the `apache_proxy` container.

Now, I went back into the `apache_proxy` container and performed the following:

```
a2ensite build.example.conf
a2ensite cicd.example.conf
service apache2 restart
```

Running `apachectl -S` from the command line of the `apache_proxy` container I can see the following is in effect:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80 is a NameVirtualHost
     default server 172.17.0.17 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost 172.17.0.17 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost build.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/build.example.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost cicd.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/cicd.example.conf:1)
```

Here is what the setup looks like:
[image: Docker VHost Example]

I can reach each individual container via it's respective port and I should be able to go to the following URL's to get to the respective sites:

build.example.com:8000 should proxy to the container/website on port 8001
cicd.example.com:8000 should proxy to the container/website on port 8002

Instead I get the following error:

> 503 Service Unavailable

Checking the logs I get the following:

```
[Mon Oct 16 21:17:32.510127 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 165:tid 140552167175936] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8001 (localhost) failed
[Mon Oct 16 21:17:32.510278 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 165:tid 140552167175936] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost) for 0s
[Mon Oct 16 21:17:32.510302 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 165:tid 140552167175936] [client 172.26.16.120:61391] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost
[Mon Oct 16 21:17:32.799053 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 166:tid 140552217532160] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8001 (localhost) failed
[Mon Oct 16 21:17:32.799232 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 166:tid 140552217532160] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost) for 0s
[Mon Oct 16 21:17:32.799256 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 166:tid 140552217532160] [client 172.26.16.120:61392] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost, referer: http://build.example.com:8000/info.php
```

I have been going down rabbit holes for the past several hours trying to get this to work and I am sure now I am missing something quite simple. Can anyone shed light on the error of my ways?

### NOTE

I followed a huge rabbit hole concerning SELinux which is not enabled or even really installed in the Ubuntu/Apache proxy container.

I should also state that I am not a network guru or master web-server configurator. I only know enough to be dangerous.

### EDIT

Based on suggestions I have tried the following:

`ProxyPass / http://cicd:80/` causes a 502 error
`ProxyPass / http://ip.address.of.server:8002/` times out
`ProxyPass / http://ip.address.of.container:8002/` causes a 503 error
`ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8002/ retry=0` causes a 503 error (suggested in other answers)

Comment: did you try `echo net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`?

Comment: Nevermind, have read again your setup and you don't need it; why you reverse proxy to localhost:8001? 8001 is the port exported to the host, while httpd is running in another container

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ Yes, 8001 is exposed to the host for port 80 inside the container. Have a look at the added diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I really needed to remember is that we’re working within Docker’s network once we pass in the request, so using things like  `ProxyPass / http://localhost:8002/` will not work because ‘localhost’ belongs to the Docker container in which we’ve made the request.

So I started searching outside of the error box, so to speak, and came upon this answer [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

What I determined is we need to pass the request to the Docker network. To get that information I ran `sudo ip addr show docker0` from the server’s command line and it returns:

```
4: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 56:84:7a:fe:97:99 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.42.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5484:7aff:fefe:9799/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Showing Docker’s internal network to be on 172.17.42.1  Changing the pass to be  `ProxyPass / http://172.17.42.1:8002/` hands off the request to the Docker network and subsequently succeeds.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName cicd.example.com
    <Proxy *>
        #Allow from localhost
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://172.17.42.1:8002/ retry=0
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Nice you found out a solution. You may want to maybe fix the IP of your other container though (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937185/assign-static-ip-to-docker-container) because your container IP may vary from one run to another

Comment: Fix the IP of the other container? Apologies, I'm not following @b.enoit.be - do you mean `build`? If so, I did, just showing one here for example.

Comment: At run time of a container you can specify an IP it will use, so you don't have the unexpected 'it was that IP before but now I relaunched it it has a different one'. Docker acts like a DHCP and just assign IP to your container(s). So you could end up having not the same IP address for the same container from one run to another.

Comment: Right - oh yes, in the production setup I am making sure IP's are assigned and 'fixed' @b.enoit.be

Comment: I am not sure this is what you really want: with your current config, the steps that follow after you open `localhost:8080` are: 1. the local socket to 8080 is connected to the proxy container port 80 2. the proxy container proxies back to host on port 8001 (172.17.42.1 is the gateway of the docker network, ie. it is same host as localhost) 3. port 8001 on the host is connected to the cicd container port 80 4. cicd serves the php page. Basically, you are going _in_, and the proxy proxies to another _in_side node via _out_side (the host itself)

Comment: Given that @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ what should I do?

Comment: Add `--link cicd:cicd` to the docker command starting the reverse proxy; then use `ProxyPass / http://cicd:80/` in the virtual host. Then do the same for the other. You don't need to expose the ports 800X in the proxied containers at all (if not for testing with a browser against them). Again, as this is untested, I am not posting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your two other containers are not localhost but respectively

- build:80
- cicd:80

Reflect that in your apache proxy and you should be good to go

Comment: So I should change the `ProxyPass` to read `/ http://build.example.com:8001` and `/ http://cicd.example.com:8002`?

Comment: more likely build:80 and cicd:80

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ correct. The names you give to a container ends up being the host name known in the docker network in between containers.

Comment: So just build:8001 and build:8002, because those are the ports. They are run with `-p 8001:80` and `-p 8002:80` respectively

Comment: Cannot test it now, but I believe you would use port 80, as it is the port open in the container; not 80XX which is the port forwarded to the host

Comment: @JayBlanchard no the port before the semicolon is actually the port exposed to your host not the port available in the network internally

Comment: OK, let me try that. I'm not sure if I have the `ProxyPass` syntax correct either. Just doing `ProxyPass / cicd:80`

Comment: With `ProxyPass / http://cicd:80/` I get the following in the log as a 502 error: `AH00898 DNS lookup failure for: cicd returned by info.php`

Comment: [Did that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46779313/how-to-cure-503-service-unavailable-in-apache-running-in-docker-container/46779440?noredirect=1#comment80505109_46779412) @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ So it appears that DNS is not locating the Docker container based on that. :-/ Let me try the full domain name. EDIT: that doesn't work.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/ You should maybe go with a link. Or even better if your containers are meant for co existence bundle them together with a docker-compose

Comment: One is meant to be a proxy for two completely independent microservices @b.enoit.be Linking would not fulfill the purpose.

Comment: See the updated question and diagram to understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: Your answer combined with other information gave me some good clues for what was wrong.