# Remote debug Node 9 in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, remote-debugging

I'm trying to remote debug nodejs 9 inside docker.

```
> testnodedockerproj@0.0.0 debug /home/deb
> node --inspect=9229 ./bin/www
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/75db828f-4b4b-491c-99d1-0eb60a82e45c
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

http://localhost:3100/ responds

```
GET /robots.txt 404 1752.471 ms - 905
GET / 304 1838.729 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 114.501 ms - -
```

But I can't connect to ws://127.0.0.1:9229/75db828f-4b4b-491c-99d1-0eb60a82e45c.

The docker compose file has this port config:

```
ports:
    - "3100:3000"
    - "9339:9229"
```

I can connect to the node debug url from inside the docker container. But I can't reach it from my host system.
The expected endpoint should be ws://127.0.0.1:9**33**9/75db828f-4b4b-491c-99d1-0eb60a82e45c and it is unaccessible.

Is there any specific docker config which enables the connection to the web socket?

How do I reach this node debug endpoint?

@Update

I've managed to connect to the debug endpoint.

The node debug command should be:

```
node --inspect=[::]:9229 ./bin/www
```

In this way I can connect to the port 9339 and attach a debugger.

Comment: Just to clarify: you're trying to connect **remotely** and using this notation `ws://127.0.0.1:9339` from your host machine?

Comment: Yes, Node is in Docker on my desktop. So, localhost should do, I hope.

Comment: So it's not remote, it's just in your docker container. You for sure need to use this port `9339` and should be able to connect here `ws://127.0.0.1:9339`.

Comment: Yes, I am supposed to be able, but I'm not. http://127.0.0.1:3100 is accessible, but ws://127.0.0.1:9339 is not.

Comment: What exact error you're getting?

Comment: Well, I try in different ways.

Chrome says: This site can’t be reached, ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME

I try websocket connection in PowerShell (my host is Windows):
(New-Object System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket).ConnectAsync($url, $CT)
but it says the destination is not reachable

Comment: I tried to set up a static ip to the container as described here [static-ip-to-docker-container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937185/assign-static-ip-to-docker-container). But I can't make it work.

Answer (score 5):

The node debug command should be:

```
node --inspect=[::]:9229 ./bin/www
```

Answer (score 0):

So here how I managed to make it work:

1. You have the container with let's say this IP: `172.1.1.10`
2. Open up Chrome dev tools: `chrome://inspect/#devices`
3. Select **configure** and add new address and port: `172.1.1.10:9229`
4. Start the container
5. Run the following command (I have Ubuntu 16.04): 
   `docker-compose exec <conainer name> node --inspect=172.1.1.10:9229 <path-to-task>`
6. Refresh you Chrome page and if you set everything correctly you will see your container under `Remote Target` label.

Comment: This was helpful to find out the solution.