# Assign docker container a static IP address in local network for development

Tags: docker, docker-compose, lan

I'm using Docker compose to set up a local development environment on Mac. I want to be able to connect to the container from the LAN (for ex, from my phone or iPad) by using a static IP, and to configure it in the docker-compose file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this post has what you're looking for: [Assign static IP to Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937185/assign-static-ip-to-docker-container)

In docker-compose, you can build out networks and attach those containers to the network, which will allow you to simulate exactly what's being noted in the above post:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#ipv4_address-ipv6_address

Answer (score -1):

In most cases a static IP wouldn’t be necessary if you expose the ports from the container to your Mac. You could reach your container by going to http://localhost:80 for example. You can specify this in your [compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports)file.