# Issue with the Docker Windows container

Tags: .net, docker, windows-10

From Visual Studio I created a .NET Framework application and hosted into a Docker Windows container. Whenever I close the project solution container is exited again when I open project new container is creating I want to us single container. My Docker is in Windows 10 Pro. I'm using a Windows container.

When I use docker inspect container id it will provide an IP address, hence I want to use a constant IP address to browse my application.

Whenever I close Visual Studio image will not appear in docker images -a list. When again I reload my project solution in Visual Studio I'm able to see the image, and when I check process `docker ps` a new container is running with a new IP address.

Is there any solution for this so that I can use a single container with a constant IP address to browse my application?

Comment: For a static address, take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937185/assign-static-ip-to-docker-container

Comment: The typical usage pattern for Docker is to use port mapping, though, so the container's internal IP address doesn't matter -- it's exposed through the local network interface.

Comment: But everytime new container is creating when i open project in  visual studio ,any chances to use same container

Comment: Hi i have tried to create staic ip but its giving error that plugins are not supported in this platform iam using my docker is installed on windows 10 and iam using windows container