# Docker how to specify an ip address with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use docker-compose to charge my container, I need to connect between container and host, so I need an ip that I always could access, I know docker's default ip on linux is `172.17.0.x`, but something strange is that every time I start up the container the ip will change, from `172.18.0.1` to `172.19.0.1` to `172.20.0.1` and etc ..., step by step

Comment: Instead of relying on the ip address, what about just using port forwarding to expose the service you need to access on the host?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assign static IP to Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937185/assign-static-ip-to-docker-container)