# Private addressable IP for Docker-Compose like Vagrant

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vagrant, docker-network

### Problem

I'm using Docker-Compose and want to set a locally-addressable IP (such as 10.1.1.100) for one of the containers. This IP is not on my host machine's subnet.

### Vagrant style

In a similar Vagrant project, there's a line:

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.1.2.100"
```

This works great in that project. I can target the machine at `10.1.2.100` as if it's an available IP on my network. I don't even have to create a subnet.

### Question

I've been looking for how I'd setup a container with a locally-addressable IP with Docker (specifically Docker-Compose), but haven't been able to get it working.

### Failed configurations

I've tried adding `networks`, and assigned a static IP with `ipv4_address: 10.1.1.100`. Sadly, it seems as though this entire network is only accessible via Docker itself, not via the host machine.

If I try to use `ports` to expose an IP as `10.1.1.100:80:80`, I get this error instead:

> Cannot start service SERVICE_NAME: Ports are not available: listen tcp 10.1.1.100:80: bind: can't assign requested address.

But this works fine if I simply put `80:80`. So it must be the IP binding that causes this issue.

I also tried setting `network_mode` on only this service and neither `host` nor `bridge` worked correctly.

Lastly, I found I could add to `driver_opts`:

```
com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4: "10.1.1.100"
```

This made it impossible to start the container similar to the same error I received when using the `ports` method.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937185/assign-static-ip-to-docker-container

Comment: Yeah, none of those work; especially not the widely-accepted answer :/.

Comment: In most environments you can't reach the container-private IP addresses from outside of Docker.  Instead you need to publish specific `ports:` from containers and you can reach them via the host's IP address.  Vagrant's VM-based networking setup is just different.

Comment: My point is that Vagrant allows reaching container private IPs, at least the exposed one, even with Docker containers. They've figured something out.