# Can Docker Host and container share the same subnet

Tags: docker, namespaces, docker-network

I know that using driver host the container would use the same network namespace but I would like to get something as in "Bridged Mode" of VirtualBox. I mean: that container to be in the same subnet that host but using different namespace.
Is that possible?

Comment: On Linux you can assign a static IP address from host's subnet to a container. All traffic to that address will be directed to the container. If that is what you want to achieve, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64643963/11344502) my answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was trying ping to my container (centos) from my host but it wasn't working.

Here is what I did to solve this. I can't guarantee any **stability** or **security** so follow this at your own risk.

**My Set-Up:** 
I have 2 different VMs (Ubuntu) running on my Vmware workstation on my host (Windows 10). I configured to use "NAT" for both my VMs.

1. My first ubuntu VM is running with default settings.
2. My second ubuntu VM: is the Docker Host. I've first installed docker on this VM.
3. After docker is successfully installed on the second ubuntu VM, i've configured the following settings: 
   a. Create a macvlan docker network as follows:

   docker network create -d macvlan -o parent=eno1 
   --subnet 192.168.1.0/24 
   --gateway 192.168.1.1 
   --ip-range 192.168.1.192/27 
   --aux-address 'host=192.168.1.223' 
   mynet \

> note: eno1 is the physical interface on your VM. Also, change the IP
> settings according to your LAN settings.

4. On the Second VM (Ubuntu docker host) configure the interface to communicate with your docker container: 
   `ip link add mynet-int link eno1 type macvlan  mode bridge`
5. After that configure the IP address and bring the interface UP:

```
ip addr add 192.168.1.223/32 dev mynet-int

ip link set mynet-int up
```

6. Finally, configure the route to your container

   ip route add 192.168.1.192/27 dev mynet-int

By following these steps I was able to put the container and the host(ubuntu VM) on the same network. Pings were successful back and forward.

Or [Just follow this post:](https://blog.oddbit.com/post/2018-03-12-using-docker-macvlan-networks/)