# Can (Should) I Run a Docker Container with Same host name as the Docker Host?

Tags: docker, url, networking, server, hostname

I have a server application (that I cannot change) that, when you connect as a client, will give you other URLs to interact with.   Those URLs are also part of the same server so the URL advertised uses the hostname of a docker container.

We are running in a mixed economy (some docker containers, some regular applications).  We actually need to set up where we have the server running as a docker application on a single VM, and that server will be accessed by non-docker clients (as well as docker clients not running on the same docker network).

So you have a server hostname (the docker container) and a docker hostname (the hostname of the VM running docker).

The client's initial connection is to:  `dockerhostname:1234` but when the server sends URLs to the client, it sends:  `serverhostname:5678` ... which is not resolvable by the client.   So far, we've addressed this by adding "server hostname " to the client's `/etc/hosts` file but this is a pain to maintain.

I have also set the `--hostname` of the server docker container to the same name as the docker host and it has mostly worked but I've seen where a docker container running on the same docker network as the server had issues connecting to the server.

I realize this is not an ideal docker setup.  We're migrating from a history of delivering as rpm's to delivering containers .. but it's a slow process.  Our company has lots of applications.

I'm really curious if anyone has advice/lessons learned with this situation.  What is the best solution to my URL problem?  (I'm guessing it is the `/etc/hosts` we're already doing)

Answer (score 1):

You can do port-mapping `-p 8080:80`

How you build and run your container?

With a shell command, dockerfile or yml file?

Check this:
[docker port](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/port/)

Call this and it will work:

**[SERVERIP][PORT FROM DOCKERHOST]**

To work with hostnames you need DNS or use hosts file.

**The hosts file solution is not a good idea, it's how the internet starts in the past ^^**
If something change you have to change all hosts files on every client!

Or use a static ip for your container:

```
docker network ls

docker network create my-network

docker network create --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 mynet123

docker run --net mynet123 --ip 172.18.0.22 -it ubuntu bash
```

[Assign static IP to Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937185/assign-static-ip-to-docker-container)

Answer (score 0):

You're describing a situation that requires a ton of work. The shortest path to success is your "adding things to `/etc/hosts` file" process. You can use configuration management, like `ansible`/`chef`/`puppet` to only have to update one location and distribute it out.

But at that point, you should look into something called "service discovery." There are a ton of ways to skin this cat, but the short of it is this. You need some place (lazy mode is DNS) that stores a database of your different machines/services. When a machine needs to connect to another machine for a service, it asks that database. Hence the "service discovery" part.

Now implementing the database is the hardest part of this, there are a bunch of different ways, and you'll need to spend some time with your team to figure out what is the best way.

Normally running an internal DNS server like `dnsmasq` or `bind` should get you most of the way, but if you need something like `consul` that's a whole other conversation. There are a lot of options, and the best thing to do is research, and audit what you actually need for your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  We are looking at ansible.  Will spend some time looking into service discovery.  Thanks again.