# Docker container can't access internet with specific ip

Tags: docker

I'm trying to assign ip address to docker container. I already tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/35359185/10956041. also tried create network with `docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=193.111.77.0/24 --gateway=193.111.77.1 br0` and assign ip to container with `docker run --net br0 --ip 193.111.77.183 -it ubuntu bash` but again can't access to internet.

Comment: How and why do you assign IP addresses to specific processes without Docker?  Could you combine this approach with `docker run -p`'s ability to publish a port on a specific host IP address?  Is there a programming-related question here that could involve some application source code, or is this just a question about routing requests to a containerized service?

Comment: Hey, @DavidMaze Sorry my english bad I didn't understand much about you said. I'm trying run application which supports linux and I want run every application in specific ip so I think maybe its good idea to use docker for it

Comment: @bioflugel I think you are looking for Cluster IP Service in Kubernetes

Comment: @OzgurSar well. I never used cluster or kubernetes before. I still thinking about connect ip to docker container of course if I can