# Package 'docker.io' has no installation candidate

Tags: linux, debian, apt

when i try to install docker.io in debian 6
by typing the command: apt-get install docker.io
the result is:

E: package 'docker.io' has no installation candidate

what is the solution?
thanks

Answer (score 16):

I was facing the same error in Ubuntu-20.04 so to resolve it, I just updated my system using the below steps:

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install docker.io`

And if you are facing this error in WSL then first install the docker desktop in Windows and then follow the above steps.

Answer (score 2):

Currently (26th May 2015) `docker.io` is [only in Testing & Sid](https://wiki.debian.org/Docker). I have `Docker version 1.6.2, build 7c8fca2` running in Jessie without any problems:

```
apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
echo "deb https://get.docker.com/ubuntu docker main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 36A1D7869245C8950F966E92D8576A8BA88D21E9
apt-get update
apt-get install -y lxc-docker
# if you have the old docker.io installed previously
update-rc.d docker remove
mv /etc/init.d/docker /etc/init.d/docker.old
systemctl unmask docker
systemctl unmask docker.socket
systemctl enable docker
```

See also [additional notes](https://it-offshore.co.uk/linux/debian/37-docker-1-6-on-debian-jessie) for enabling custom startup options & also [static ip addresses in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30271170/555451).

Answer (score 0):

Docker is supported only in debian wheezy and jessie 64bit versions. For more details you may see this:

[Official docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/installation/debian/)

Comment: i try to add it but nothing is changed. the same problem is resulted

Comment: add what? if you are refering to the ppa, then of course if won't work. And even if you manage to install it somehow, you yet need to install new kernel, otherwise it won't run.