# Error setting up docker on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, docker-machine

I am trying to set up docker machine on Windows and this problem has annoyed me for a few days.

I downloaded and installed DockerToolbox-1.9.1a on my Windows, so it came with Virtual Box version 5.0.10. After that I ran this command to create my virtual machine:

**docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --engine-insecure-registry docker.pre-prod.ss.local:5000 --virtualbox-hostonly-cidr 192.168.99.100/24 mymachine**

Here is what I got:

> Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
>   Machine is running, waiting for SSH to be available... Detecting
>   operating system of created instance... Detecting the provisioner...
>   Provisioning created instance... Copying certs to the local machine
>   directory... Copying certs to the remote machine... Setting Docker
>   configuration on the remote daemon... WARNING >>> This machine has
>   been allocated an IP address, but Docker Machine could not reach it
>   successfully.
>
> SSH for the machine should still work, but connecting to exposed
>   ports, such as the Docker daemon port (usually :2376), may not
>   work properly.
>
> You may need to add the route manually, or use another related
>   workaround
>
> This could be due to a VPN, proxy, or host file configuration issue.
>
> You also might want to clear any VirtualBox host only interfaces you
>   are not using

The machine was created successfully. So I ran the docker-machine env command:

**docker-machine env --shell=powershell mymachine| Invoke-Expression**

and I got:

> Error running connection boilerplate: Error checking and/or
>   regenerating the certs: There was icates for host
>   "192.168.99.100:2376": dial tcp 192.168.99.100:2376: connectex: No
>   connection target machine actively refused it. You can attempt to
>   regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate-certs name'. Be
>   advised that this will trigger a Docker daemon restart which will stop
>   running containers.

Running **docker version** returned

> Client:  Version:      1.9.1  API version:  1.21  Go version:
>   go1.4.3  Git commit:   a34a1d5  Built:        Fri Nov 20 17:56:04 UTC
>   2015  OS/Arch:      windows/amd64 An error occurred trying to connect:
>   Get http://localhost:2375/v1.21/version: dial tcp  connection could be
>   made because the target machine actively refused it.

Can someone help to point out the direction to fix this issue? It is really troublesome to set up docker on Windows. Thank you very much.

Comment: Try this workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34641003/error-checking-tls-connection-error-checking-and-or-regenerating-the-certs

Answer (score 2):

I use docker 1.9.1 on Windows (7, 8 and even 10), but without docker registry, and without using `--virtualbox-hostonly-cidr`.

If you are to use that last option, check "[Set a specific address ip when i create a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29701316/6309)", where I mention issue 1709, which uses cidr in `.1`, not `.100` (but getting a `.100` ip address as a result):

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-hostonly-cidr "192.168.99.1/24" m99
```

> If there's no other machine with the same [cidr (Classless Inter-Domain Routing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing), the machine should always get the `.100` IP upon start.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried to use 192.168.99.1/24, but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: @TonyVu I have added another alternative using `ifconfig` in http://stackoverflow.com/a/29701316/6309: maybe that can help. Look for the section titled "Another workaround:"