# how to set docker host ip in container

Tags: docker, ip

here's a docker conainer, providing html interface for user to set host pub ip address. 
host is CentOS system, 
container mount with

```
-v /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts:/host_network-scripts
```

to change if-eth0 static ip.

but ifup or /etc/init.d/network cannot called in conainer, due to related scripts in host system.

is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/a/29701316/6309 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/34336489/6309 help?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question, but if you are looking for a mean to pass the IP address from the host into the container then I suggest you to use the `--env` flag with the command `docker run`: `-e, --env=[] Set environment variables`